# Lookup multiple-values on form-library sharepoint 2010 for InfoPath Form

Tags: document-library, infopath, lookup-column, form, multiple-values

I use InfoPath form template for a form library without coding. I want to get multiple-value of lookup to another list items. For lookup I should use sharepoint 2010 column due to no such data type in InfoPath. Unfortunately no multiple value allowed for form library although this could be done for list column.

Is there any advise how to use multiple lookup on form library sharepoint ?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to look up values from a form library in an infopath form in that same library?

Comment: I just want to use look-up values to other list item, could be form library.

Comment: Even while in the library-setting I could not add Lookup with Allow multiple values. Error in red texr occured: Earlier versions of client programs might not support a lookup column that allows multiple selections. Adding this column might block those programs from saving documents to this library. Check picture on: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-Di54S42i68E/T7Cd4Zm_vbI/AAAAAAAAA5k/uM6s_vU1jR8/w497-h373/SH2012ErrMultipleLookup.JPG